# Add comma on input text that reference a decimal value

Tags: apex, visualforce, inputtext, decimal

I have an inner class that has decimal attribute. This attribute is referenced by an input:text field on visual force. My question is how can I add thousand comma separation on this input text? e.g 1000 to 1,000

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you are trying to achieve? Are you trying to modify the user input as they type? When it gets bound to the controller? It would be straightforward to output with commas, but with inputs it's not as clear what you are asking.

Comment: apologies if this confuse you. i just want to mimic the behavior of standard currency fields wherein commas are added/accepted when inputting a values in currency field. but my problem is that it is an input text and it is referencing a decimal value from an inner class.

Comment: Not sure if this gets you where you want, so I won't post as an answer. But perhaps `<apex:input type="number">` will help you.